# Objective-C function argument and static variable same name

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having some issue about naming overridings of static variables in objective-c.

My .h file is:

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface FetchClass : NSObject

+ (void)initWithNSManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext;
@end
```

And my .m file is:

```
static NSManagedObjectContext * managedObjectContext;

    @implementation FetchClass 

    + (void)initWithNSManagedObjectContext: (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext{
        FetchClass.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext; 
    }
```

However, I get the error

"Property managedObjectContext not found on object of type FetchTasks"

So, the problem is, function argument `managedObjectContext` is of course overriding the static variable of the same name. That is why I have to get the static variable through Class.staticVariableName. But this time I get error as I mentioned above.

However If I change the static variable name to some other name , like:

```
static NSManagedObjectContext * managedObjectContextOtherName;

@implementation FetchClass 

+ (void)initWithNSManagedObjectContext: (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext{
    managedObjectContextOtherName = managedObjectContext;
}
```

It works perfectly.  My question is that, how to use these variables (static variable and function argument variable) if they have same name?

Comment: You don't. Give your static variables and local variables unique names if you want to be able to access both.

Comment: That's the whole point of the convention for prefixing local variables with an underscore `_` as is done automatically if you use `@properties`.

Comment: how do you think _class_ methods can access to any _instance_ methods or properties? you might have been missed a couple of essential classes in the school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *static variable*, like your `managedObjectContext`, is the closest thing to a *class variable* that Objective-C provides **but** it is not the same thing and this is why you get errors doing what you are trying - you cannot resolve your reference by qualifying it with the class name.

In (Objective-)C a static variable declared outside of any function/method has *global lifetime* and *file scope* - i.e. the variable always exists but is only visible from within the same source file as its declaration. There is no "file scope" qualifier you can use to resolve ambiguity/hiding when reference a static, any variable with the same name in an inner scope will hide the static.

In your case you can just use:

```
+ (void)initWithNSManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)_managedObjectContext
{
   managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext; 
}
```

(And there is no need to change your declaration of `initWithNSManagedObjectContext:` in the interface - parameter names are not required to match - so your "public" declaration doesn't require _'s in the names if you don't wish it to.)

Answer (score 0):

Method arguments and instance variable should have different names. When they are the same, the compiler should warn you that it using the method variable.